# Why i take 404 error when i reload the page

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, fuse

I used fuse template to build an angular project. I made it but when i reload the page website are broken. This is the mistake output:

**Server Error
404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.**

Comment: Look at your browser's dev-tool's Network tab.

Comment: There is nothing over there. Same mistake 404 Not Found

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting what the Network tab is telling you: **yes** it's going to say there's a 404 error, but it will also show you the details of the failed request which you should be able to use to diagnose _why_ it's failing, and what caused the failed request in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

check the app.module.ts  and add HashLocationStrategy

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';
import {LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';

import {MyApp} from './myapp';

bootstrap(MyApp, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i do not know how to implement it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: can you share the app.module.ts file

Answer (score 0):

Here is my app.module.ts code=>

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ExtraOptions, PreloadAllModules, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { MarkdownModule } from 'ngx-markdown';
import { FuseModule } from '@fuse';
import { FuseConfigModule } from '@fuse/services/config';
import { FuseMockApiModule } from '@fuse/lib/mock-api';
import { CoreModule } from 'app/core/core.module';
import { appConfig } from 'app/core/config/app.config';
import { mockApiServices } from 'app/mock-api';
import { LayoutModule } from 'app/layout/layout.module';
import { AppComponent } from 'app/app.component';
import { appRoutes } from 'app/app.routing';

const routerConfig: ExtraOptions = {
    preloadingStrategy       : PreloadAllModules,
    scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'
};

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports     : [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, routerConfig),

        // Fuse, FuseConfig & FuseMockAPI
        FuseModule,
        FuseConfigModule.forRoot(appConfig),
        FuseMockApiModule.forRoot(mockApiServices),

        // Core module of your application
        CoreModule,

        // Layout module of your application
        LayoutModule,

        // 3rd party modules that require global configuration via forRoot
        MarkdownModule.forRoot({})
    ],
    bootstrap   : [
        AppComponent,
    ],
})
export class AppModule
{
}
```